# Grammar of the yet in the sentence

Tags: grammar

I am reading [a topic](https://www.economist.com/united-states/2021/07/31/joe-bidens-bipartisan-dream-lives-on-for-now) on `The Economist`, and crossing to this sentence:

> Yet legislation encoding this deal has yet to be written, much less
> passed

I usually see the usage of `yet` as the contradiction, when putting at the beginning of a sentence, as the following example:

> It was raining hard. Yet she didn’t put on her wellington boots.

`Yet` on the first sentence seems not to follow this convention.

Comment: What is the preceding sentence that the "yet" would be linking it to?

Comment: Do you mean the first 'yet' or the second one?

Answer (score 1):

In the first quoted example sentence, which reads

> Yet legislation encoding this deal has yet to be written, much less passed

the first *Yet* does have the meaning of being a "contradiction", as in *however* (meaning *on the other hand*) and this usage employs [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet) 3 for the word *yet*.

The second *yet* has the meaning of *up to now; so far* and employs Merriam-Webster definition 2a(1) for the word *yet*.

In your second quoted example sentence, the word *yet* employs Merriam-Webster definition number 3.

In every usage here, the word is an adverb.